# URL format updated - how to redirect to new format

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, redirect, url-rewriting

I recently updated the format of URLs on my site, example below:

**Old URL:**
www.domain-name.com/article/200/title-of-the-article/

**New URL:**
www.domain-name.com/article/200/2015/05/title-of-the-article/

How can I perfom the redirect in `.htaccess` to automatically get the **new URL**. Lets say the user inputs `www.my-domain.com/article/200/title-of-the-article/` then this page would automatically be redirected to `www.my-domain.com/article/200/2015/05/title-of-the-article/`. Basically to fix previously shared URLs on social media sites.

Code below:

```
RewriteRule ^article/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/(.*)/$ mainarticle.php?article_id=$1 [NC]
```

rule that accepts the updated url.

Trying to perform a redirect here:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond ^article/([0-9]+)/(.*)/$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^article/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/(.*)/$ [R=301,L]
```

Comment: @MikeRockett yep, trying to perform a 301 redirect, doesn't seem to get it to work and I'm not sure if that is the solution to this.

Comment: You're going to land up creating rules for every single article as mod_rewrite cannot guess the `2015/05` part, which I assume is dynamic.

Comment: Can you share the code you've tried?

Comment: @MikeRockett No hope for regular expressions?

Comment: Updated my question with code.

Comment: I don't think you've grasped the concept of how mod_rewrite works. It simply cannot guess the second and third parameters. I suggest you read over some [documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) before trying to work with [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html).